# Why is it harder to see rain through a glass window?

Tags: optics, visible-light, everyday-life, water, glass

Every time it rains mildly, I can hardly, *if at all*, see it through a glass window. If I open the window, I see just fine - and it can be raining hard enough to require an umbrella for a short walk.

The windows are fairly good noise-blockers, but are otherwise 'fully' transparent to visible light (as far as  I can see). I also notice the effect to be stronger at night, but can't see much even under an intense street lamp.

So what is it about such glass that's transparent to visible light yet blocks off light reflected from raindrops? Or vice versa - what change  does light undergo post-reflection that is responsible?

Comment: Is there rain on the window? You can see rain here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iLs04Z6uBqU

Comment: @user47014 Minimal if any rain on the window - it's shielded by surrounding walls - and the windows are clear

Comment: I suffer the opposite; sometimes I look through the window and I think there are tiny raindrops falling, but there are not.

Comment: Maybe you could take a video/photo of looking at rain through and not through a window

Comment: The glass is usually dirty with dust which adds noise that raises the threshold for detection